# How to filter String in where clause

Tags: sql, hana

I would like to extract the string using where clause in SAP HANA.For an example,these are 3 strings for name column.

```
123._SYS_BIC.meag.app.qthor.cidwh_eingangsschicht.backend.dblayer.l2.checks/MasterData_Holdings.
153._SYS_BIC.meag.app.qthor.centralAdministration.backend.dblayer.l2.checks/AuditAndSecurities.
meag.app.qthor.centralAdministration.backend.dblayer.l2.checks/GeneralLedger
```

After filter the name column using where clause, output in the name column would be shown only the last portion of the string. So, output will be like this. That means whatever we have, just remove from the beginning till '/'.

"MasterData_Holdings"
"AuditAndSecurities"
"GeneralLedger"

Comment: [SUBSTR_AFTER](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20e7fb71751910148292a53e1b4a9bba.html) look like it could be used, but  i do not know HANA.....

Comment: thnx, it works..

Comment: @suncatcher I see that you restored the SAP tag. Not very important to me if you want to have this tag applied, but in case you see that I remove the SAP tag from recent and future questions, I do it because it's a company, not a product or tool name. It has been marked "ambiguous" so it should not be used (same as Microsoft, there's no question tagged Microsoft, so there should be no question tagged SAP). Cheers.

Comment: @SandraRossi, for me it seems more logical to have all SAP-scope in one tag, many SAP technologies correlate with each other, so it is useful to have them in one place. So marking this tag as ambiguous is disputable. Maybe it's worth starting a discussion on a https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: @Suncatcher Thanks. The SAP tag was made ambiguous on July 25th, 2020. I guess the initiator and approvers didn't have a in-depth discussion but who knows. I agree with their choice, but feel free to start a discussion and I will argument on it.

Comment: @SandraRossi [added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402154/what-to-do-with-sap-tag) the question, feel free to discuss

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [REPLACE_REGEXPR](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/dcf1045ce51d45119cfe8ba17cf9da4f.html)

I'm not familiar myself with Hana but the function is pretty straight forward and it should be:

```
select REPLACE_REGEXPR('.+/(.+)' IN fieldName WITH '\1' OCCURRENCE ALL) as field
...
where
... -- your filter
```

Be aware that this regex `'.+/(.+)'` will eat everything until the last `/` so for instance if you have `....checks/MasterData_Holdings/Something` it will return only `Something`